# For $x\geq 0$, is $\sqrt{x}$ the magnitude of $x^{1/2}$?

Tags: radicals

### Motivation

\begin{align}
 4^{1/2} &=
    \begin{cases}
       \left(2^2\right)^{1/2}\\
       \left(\left(-2\right)^2\right)^{1/2}
    \end{cases} \\
   &=
    \begin{cases}
       2\\
       -2
    \end{cases} 
\end{align}

And $\sqrt{4}=2$ (by definition)

### Question

Can I conclude that $\sqrt{x}$ is the magnitude of $x^{1/2}$ for $x\geq 0$?

Comment: $\sqrt x$ and $x^{1/2}$ stand for the same thing and both of them are nonnegative numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule that you used $x^{ab}=(x^a)^b$ is true only when $x \ge 0$ you can't use it when $x=-2$, and as Kavi Rama Murthy said $\sqrt x=x^{1/2} \ge 0$

Comment: It is by convention rule?

Comment: Maybe we can call it so, but the reason why it is not true is that if it is true then $-1=(-1)^1=(-1)^{(2).(1/2)}=((-1)^2)^{1/2})=1^{1/2}=1$